# I get error MockMultipartFile Error 415,err cast, error 400, Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

I want test con Mockito, My controller gets 3 String, 1 File, 1 class

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/insertExcel", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "multipart/form-data")
@ResponseBody
public MyMessage insertExcel(@RequestPart("period") String period, @RequestPart("commentary") String commentary,
        @RequestPart("idProcess") String idProcess, @RequestPart("uploadFile") MultipartFile multipart,
        @RequestPart("dataUser") DataUser dataUser) {


    return this.mlService.insertFile(multipart, dataUser, idProcess, period, commentary);
}
```

Then I want simulate this with mockito:

```
     MockMultipartFile file1 = new MockMultipartFile("period", "202001", "text/plain", "202001".getBytes());
     MockMultipartFile file2 = new MockMultipartFile("commentary", "comentario", "text/plain", "comentario".getBytes());
     MockMultipartFile file3 = new MockMultipartFile("idProcess", "process1", "text/plain", "process1".getBytes());
     MockMultipartFile file4 = new MockMultipartFile("uploadFile", "uploadFile", "text/plain", "uploadFile".getBytes());
     MockMultipartFile file5 = new MockMultipartFile("dataUser", "as", "text/plain", "{\"createDate\": \"2020\", \"createUser\": \"test\",   \"modificationDate\":\"2020\", \"modificationUser\": \"test\" }".getBytes()) ;


    this.webMvcMock.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.fileUpload("/ml/insertExcel")
            .file(file1)
            .file(file2)
            .file(file3)
            .file(file4)
            .file(file5)).
            andExpect(status().isOk());
```

Error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<415>
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:54)
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:81)
```

When I run this, I get error 415 why ??
How can I send the data correctly? Thanks

**Edit**:

I think what I get error 415 because in my controller I have consumes = "multipart/form-data"), so, I add in my test :

```
this.webMvcMock.perform((RequestBuilder) ((ResultActions) ((MockMultipartHttpServletRequestBuilder) ((MockMultipartHttpServletRequestBuilder) ((MockMultipartHttpServletRequestBuilder) ((MockMultipartHttpServletRequestBuilder) MockMvcRequestBuilders.fileUpload("/ml/insertExcel")
        .file(file1).contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA))
        .file(file2).contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA))
        .file(file3).contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA))
        .file(file4).contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA))
        .file(file5).contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)).
        andExpect(status().isOk()));
```

Now the new error is:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMultipartHttpServletRequestBuilder cannot be cast to org.springframework.test.web.servlet.ResultActions
    at es.ApplicationTests.insertExcel1(ApplicationTests.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
```

**Edit2**:

I modified the call to controller but I now other error:

```
 MockMultipartFile file1 = new MockMultipartFile("period", "202001", "text/plain", "202001".getBytes());
 MockMultipartFile file2 = new MockMultipartFile("commentary", "comentario", "text/plain", "comentario".getBytes());
 MockMultipartFile file3 = new MockMultipartFile("idProcess", "process1", "text/plain", "process1".getBytes());
 MockMultipartFile file4 = new MockMultipartFile("uploadFile", "uploadFile", "text/plain", "uploadFile".getBytes());
 MockMultipartFile file5 = new MockMultipartFile("dataUser", "", "text/plain", "{\"createDate\": \"2020\", \"createUser\": \"test\",   \"modificationDate\":\"2020\", \"modificationUser\": \"test\" }".getBytes()) ;

MockHttpServletRequestBuilder request = post("/ml/insertExcel");
request.content(file1.getBytes());
request.content(file2.getBytes());
request.content(file3.getBytes());
request.content(file4.getBytes());
request.content(file5.getBytes());
request.accept(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
request.contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
this.webMvcMock.perform(request).andExpect(status().isOk());
```

The now error is 400:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<400>
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:54)
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:81)
```

I don't care how to do it, but I need you to fill in the data to the controller